# AJAX: Problems returning multiple variables

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

First off sorry if I'm missing something simple just started working with AJAX today.  I have an issue where I'm trying to get information from my database, but different records have different amounts of values.  For instance, each record has a "features" column.  In the features column I store a string. (ex: Feature1~Feature2~Feature3~Feature4... )  When I'm building the object I take apart the string and store all the features into an array.  Some objects can have 1 feature others can have up to whatever.  So... how do I return this values back to my ajax function from my php page?  Below is my ajax function that I was trying and I'll provide a link with my php file. [ next.php :  http://pastebin.com/SY74jV7X ]

```
$("a#next").click(function()
{
    $.ajax({
           type : 'POST',
           url  : 'next.php',
           dataType : 'json',
           data     : { nextID : $("a#next").attr("rel") },
           success  : function ( data ) {

                      var lastID = $("a#next").attr("rel");
                      var originID = $("a#next").attr("rev");

                      if(lastID == 1)
                      {
                        lastID = originID;  
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        lastID--;
                      }


                      $("img#spotlight").attr("src",data.spotlightimage);
                      $("div#showcase h1").text(data.title);
                      $("div#showcase h2").text(data.subtitle);
                      $("div#showcase p").text(data.description);
                      $("a#next").attr("rel", lastID);


                      for(var i=0; i < data.size; i++)
                      {
                          $("ul#features").append("<li>").text(data.feature+i).append("</li>");
                      }

                      /*
                      for(var j=1; j < data.picsize; j++)
                      {
                          $("div.thumbnails ul").append("<li>").text(data.image+j).append("</li>");
                      }
                      */                          
           },
           error    : function ( XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     $("div#showcase h1").text("An error has occured: " + errorThrown);
           }
    });
});
```

Comment: It'd help if you posted the HTML. Is the `<a>`'s `rel` the string `'Feature1~Feature2~Feature3~Feature4'`?

Comment: so the <a>'s rel equals a number. (ex. "3") I then take that number and on line 13 of next.php I get the row from the database that's id corresponds to that number. The string 'Feature1~Feature2...' is gathered in the function used on line 16 of next.php.  I get the string then use php's explode function to get the individual features and store them in the array '$features' seen on line 16 of next.php

I figured this might be more helpful than the html. (if you really need html i can post) [entry class: http://pastebin.com/sLt10srM ] 

Thanks for taking the time to check out my problem! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First replace the below in your `next.php` file:

```
for ( $i=0; $i < $arraySize; $i++ )
{
    $return['feature'.$i.''] = $features[0];
}
```

With:

```
$return['features'] = $features;
```

P.S: the current code is wrong you should have `... = $features[$i];` anyway, you don't need that just send the array as is. and then in the JS part replace:

```
for(var i=0; i < data.size; i++)
{
    $("ul#features").append("<li>").text(data.feature+i).append("</li>");
}
```

With:

```
$.each(data.features, function(k,v){
    var li = '<li>' + v + '</li>';
    $("ul#features").append(li);
});
```

This way, don't need the `data.size` anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Going to try reworking it now and will post back.  I didn't think to pass it as an array ;(

Comment: Well it worked great. Only thing I had to add was 
$("ul.features li").remove();
So that it would remove the previous entries features from ul.features

Thanks again !